# Unable to open .Net framework 4 project in visual studio 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have a .net framework 4 project which im trying to open on visual studio 2010 and it gives me the popup window saying

> The solution or project you are opening must be converted. It was
>   either created in a previous version of Visual Studio or relies on an
>   older version of a program that you have installed on your computer

This project is working fine on other machines. Also im working on many other .net framework 4 project on my machine and they are working fine. What could be the problem?

My visual studio version is 10.0.30319.1

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the project file and compare it with other project files of a similar type. Is it trying to include any "special" targets which may use some extension which was installed on the machine it was created on, for example?

If you strip it down to just a bare project (maybe with just one file) on a machine where it *does* work, it should be easy to compare that to a "fresh" project of the same kind.